# problems removing newline character in python

Tags: python, newline

I've also tried using newString.strip('\n') in addition to the ones already in the code, but it doesn't do anything. I am inputing a .fasta file which shouldn't be a problem. Thanks in advance.

```
def createLists(fil3):
    f = open(fil3, "r")
    text = f.read()

    listOfSpecies = []
    listOfSequences = []

    i = 0
    check = 0

    while (check != -1):
        startIndex = text.find(">",i)
        endIndex = text.find("\n",i)
        listOfSpecies.append(text[startIndex+1:endIndex])

        if(text.find(">",endIndex) != -1):
            i = text.find(">",endIndex)
            newString = text[endIndex+1: i]
            newString.strip()
            newString.splitlines()
            listOfSequences.append(newString)

        else:
            newString = text[endIndex+1:]
            newString.strip()
            newString.strip('\n')
            listOfSequences.append(newString)
            return (listOfSpecies,listOfSequences)


def cluster(fil3):
    print createLists(fil3)


cluster("ProteinSequencesAligned.fasta")
```

Comment: What's wrong with just iterating over the file?

Comment: try adding a print newString before stripping to debug

Comment: I have and there is no difference before and after the strip which seems odd to me

Comment: Try print repr(newString) before and after strip, if it doesn't show \n before strip then the string never had a newline

Comment: both have newstrings. This is what a fasta file looks like

Comment: >Baboon
-VHLTPEEKNAVTALWGKVNVDEVGGEALGRLLVVYPWTQRFFDSFGDLSSPAAVMGNPKVKAHGKKVLGAF
SDGLNHLDNLKGTFAQLSELHCDKLHVDPENFKLLGNVLVCVLAHHFGKEFTPQVQAAYQKVVAGVANALAH
KYH
>Galago
-VHLTPDEKNAVCALWGKVNVEEVGGEALGRLLVVYPWTQRFFDSFGDLSSPSAVMGNPKVKAHGKKVLSAF
SDGLQHLDNLCGTFAKLSELHCDKLHVNPENFRLLGNVLVCVLAHHFGKDFTPEVQAAYEKVVAGVATALAH
KYH
>Colobus
MVHLTPDEKAAVTALWGKVNVDEVGGEALGRLLVVYPWTQRFFESFGDLSSPDAVMGNPKVKAHGKKVLGAF
SDGLAHLDNLKGTFAQLSELHCDKLHVDPENFKLLGNVLVCVLAHHFGKEFTPQVQAAYQKVVAGVANALAH
KYH

Comment: with a newline before every '>'

Comment: and within the protein sequences

Comment: If the newline is not at the end strip wont do anything(strip strips from right and left ends. splitline gets rid of newlines

Comment: I also tried splitline(in the code)

Comment: When you have read the file, you should close it with `f.close()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable:

```
In [1]: s = 'lala\n'

In [2]: s.strip()
Out[2]: 'lala'

In [3]: s
Out[3]: 'lala\n'

In [4]: s = s.strip()

In [5]: s
Out[5]: 'lala'
```

So just do:

```
new_string = text[end_index+1:].strip()
```

And please follow PEP 8.
Also, you could rewrite your loop just using a for loop over the lines. Python files support direct iteration:

```
In [6]: with open('download.py') as fobj:
   ...:     for line in fobj:
   ...:         print line
```

And if you don't use the `with` statement, make sure you close the file with the `close()` method at the end of your function.

Comment: Edited to give a couple of suggestions.

Comment: Thank you, I just replaced the strip with splitlines. Also is the PEP 8 comment in reference to the naming of newString rather than new_string?

Comment: @AlbertoDoes: It's a general advice: most for variables naming, but also for spaces (for example around operators), or conditionals (`if cond or cond2` is better than `if(cond) or (cond2)`).

Comment: Great, thanks for the advice. I didn't realize the splitline method made new additions to the list. I found a way around the problem by using new_string = text[endIndex+1:].replace('\n', '')

Answer (score 0):

Well In the end I found the best solution to be new_string = text[endIndex+1:].replace('\n', '')